# Scala streams with array/vector performance characteristics

Tags: scala, functional-programming, stream, dynamic-programming

I am taking a class on algorithms, and I'm solving a few exercises on dynamic programming right now.

I looked up how I would solve some of the problems in a functional way in Scala, and from what I read from the scaladoc on the standard library, I found stream, view, and iterator as something that might be plausible.

But I would be using a lot of random access, so Streams would be extremely inefficient since singly linked lists take O(n) time for indexed accesses. Views, as far as I know, can't be used to build something infinite, and iterators, which can be infinite, don't store any values inside themselves.

And then, I found this from the [haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Dynamic_programming_example), and this is exactly what I need, except that it is in Haskell:

```
import Data.Array
import Control.Monad(guard,mplus)

buy n = r!n
    where r = listArray (0,n) (Just (0,0,0) : map f [1..n])
          f i = do (x,y,z) <- attempt (i-6)
                   return (x+1,y,z)
                `mplus`
                do (x,y,z) <- attempt (i-9)
                   return (x,y+1,z)
                `mplus`
                do (x,y,z) <- attempt (i-20)
                   return (x,y,z+1)
          attempt x = guard (x>=0) >> r!x
```

What would be a good way to translate this into Scala? I have a feeling that I would need to import an external library (like scalaz) (but I won't be able to turn in the assignment) or write a new Stream implementation based on Scala Array or Vector.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Views, as far as I know, can't be used to build something infinite, and iterators, which can be infinite, don't store any values inside themselves.

The Haskell solution isn't infinite either.

> What would be a good way to translate this into Scala?

I'd start with defining

```
class Lazy[A](calculation: => A) {
  lazy val value: A = calculation
}
```

`=> A` is a by-name parameter, which means when you write `val x = Lazy { ... }`, the code inside `...` isn't executed immediately; instead it will be when `value` is accessed.

Then use `Array[Lazy[A]]` (`Array[Lazy[(Int, Int, Int)]]` for this specific function).